# How to transpose table data into a matrix form

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider the following table

```
user_id  group_id  other_data
-----------------------------
1        6         foo
1        7         bar
2        7         foobar
2        8         baz
2       10         barbaz
3        8         foobaz
```

I need a query to output the following:

```
user_id  group_6  group_7  group_8  group_9  group_10
-----------------------------------------------------
1        x        x
2                 x        x                 x
3                          x
```

In other words: an overview that shows which groups a user is part of.

Is this possible in SQL? I know this probably goes against what a database is meant for (it is more presentation than extracting data) but it would be great if I did not have to fiddle with long lists coming in raw form from the first table.

I have Googled on searchterms such as `"transpose rows to columns SQL Server"` and I believe I need `pivot()` but can't figure out how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: PIVOT sounds right. Why don't you give it a try and post your attempt here? We can help you correct it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method - 1 :**

You have to achieve this by `PIVOT` with dynamic query

May be something like this.

```
DECLARE @Cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@Query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Cols = STUFF((SELECT Distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(C.group_id) 
            FROM table1 C
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'')

SET @Query = 'SELECT user_id, ' + @Cols + ' FROM 
              (
                SELECT user_id,other_data,group_id
                FROM table1
              ) X
              Pivot 
              (
                MAX(other_data)
                FOR group_id IN (' + @cols + ')
              ) P '


Execute (@Query)
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/91fb7/5)

Output would be

```
USER_ID  6     7      8       10
1        foo   bar   (null)  (null)
2       (null) foobar baz    barbaz
3       (null) (null) foobaz (null)
```

**Method - 2 :**

If your `group_id` id fixed then you can proceed with normal `pivot`

```
SELECT  * 
FROM  table1 T
PIVOT
   ( 
    MAX(other_data) FOR group_id IN ([6],[7],[8],[9],[10]) 
   ) P;
```

Output would be

```
USER_ID  6     7      8       9      10
1        foo   bar   (null)  (null)  (null)
2       (null) foobar baz    (null)  barbaz
3       (null) (null) foobaz (null)  (null)
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/91fb7/6)

Comment: Since the number of groups and the their names changes regularly, hardcoding is not an option. I really like the way you create a dynamic select list in Method -1. However, I get an error: `The name 'select user_id, [Demo Group],[Domain Users],[Layout 1 Reviewers],...,[Layout N Reviewe' is not a valid identifier`. It looks like my list of groups is so long that the list is being truncated?

Comment: Anyone? I have been struggeling with this for some time now :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to PIVOT the data:

### [Demo SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e4499/2)

**Setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([user_id] int, [group_id] int, [other_data] varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([user_id], [group_id], [other_data])
VALUES
    (1, 6, 'foo'),
    (1, 7, 'bar'),
    (2, 7, 'foobar'),
    (2, 8, 'baz'),
    (2, 10, 'barbaz'),
    (3, 8, 'foobaz');
```

**SQL Pivot:**

```
;WITH PivotSource
AS
(
    SELECT   t.[user_id], t.[group_id]  
     FROM    Table1 t
)

SELECT  * 
FROM    PivotSource  
 PIVOT   ( max(group_id) FOR group_id IN ([6],[7],[8],[9],[10]) ) pvt;
```

**Output:**

```
| USER_ID |      6 |      7 |      8 |      9 |     10 |
|---------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|       1 |      6 |      7 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       2 | (null) |      7 |      8 | (null) |     10 |
|       3 | (null) | (null) |      8 | (null) | (null) |
```